# "bosh deploy" failed and reporting "Fetching package blob: Getting blob from inner blobstore: SHA1 mismatch."

Tags: virtualbox, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am deploying Cloud Foundry on VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro with a 8G memory. By default, the VirtualBox will start a "bosh-lite_default_xxxxxxx" VM with more than 6G base memory and 4 CPU processors. However, this setting will lead my Mac hang while executing "bosh deploy".

I know the practice is using a machine with memory >=16G for Cloud Foundry deployment. But this is the machine I only have.

So I changed Vagrantfile for bosh-lite like below and changed the base memory to 3G and only use 2 CPU processors.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=777"] # ensure any VM user can create files in subfolders - eg, /vagrant/tmp
  override.vm.box_version = '9000.91.0' # ci:replace
  # To use a different IP address for the bosh-lite director, uncomment this line:
  # override.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.59.4', id: :local
  v.memory = 3144
  v.cpus = 2
end
```

After the change, the "bosh-lite_default_xxxxxx" VM can still be started successfully after running "vagrant reload" after saving Vagrantfile.

Then when I run "bosh deploy", the machine is not hang any more.But it failed and reported:

Started updating job api_z1 > api_z1/0 (68c148e3-2c89-4f75-86c7-ed0945cd1158). Failed: Action Failed get_task: Task 98721dd2-35f1-49ea-6429-15ec2373a9d2 result: Applying: Applying job cloud_controller_ng: Applying package buildpack_php for job cloud_controller_ng: Fetching package blob: Getting blob from inner blobstore: SHA1 mismatch. Expected 7ef00b2e07b20b07fbf50d133bdaca6ac5164ee4, got b79493b83a7241f685ca027d667898f452e7d592 for blob /var/vcap/data/tmp/bosh-blobstore-externalBlobstore-Get861882783 (00:01:11)

Error 450001: Action Failed get_task: Task 98721dd2-35f1-49ea-6429-15ec2373a9d2 result: Applying: Applying job cloud_controller_ng: Applying package buildpack_php for job cloud_controller_ng: Fetching package blob: Getting blob from inner blobstore: SHA1 mismatch. Expected 7ef00b2e07b20b07fbf50d133bdaca6ac5164ee4, got b79493b83a7241f685ca027d667898f452e7d592 for blob /var/vcap/data/tmp/bosh-blobstore-externalBlobstore-Get861882783

Task 90 error

I googled "Fetching package blob: Getting blob from inner blobstore: SHA1 mismatch" and found someone said increasing microbosh volume from 4G to 8G resolved this error (see https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!topic/bosh-users/Rgx_HFCHenA). But I don't know how to change the microbes volume.

Anyone can share some light to me for this error? And how to change the microbes volume?

Thanks much!

Comment: If you're just trying to play around with Cloud Foundry (and don't necessarily care about the BOSH part) you can use MicroPCF.  Has a much smaller memory footprint, and just starts when you `vagrant up`, no need for `bosh deploy`: https://github.com/pivotal-cf/micropcf